# How to hide a facet item if it does not narrow the results?

Tags: 9, search

I have a facet of taxonomy terms with the links widget.
There are 3 taxonomy terms displaying with the number of results in the bracket.

```
Term 1 (3)
Term 2 (2)
Term 3 (10)
```

When I select `Term 1`, the search page displays 3 results, which is fine. But count on `Term 2` and `Term 3` are still 2 and 10 respectively, which is wrong. It should be decreased. Like for example, In those 3 results, there is only one item that has `Term 2` selected. So in that case the `Term 2` count should be 1.
So it should be like this

```
Term 1 (3) => This is now selected.
Term 2 (1)
Term 3 (2)
```

What options should I select in the facet configuration to achieve this?

I have tried with the options `Hide non-narrowing results` but no luck. I am using the `AND` operator.